# Does Context.registerReceiver() register only when Application is running?

Tags: android

I wonder one thing about android `Context.registerReceiver()` and I see on android website it said this

> There are two ways to make a broadcast receiver known to the system: One is declare it in the manifest file with this element. The other is to create the receiver dynamically in code and register it with the `Context.registerReceiver()` method

My question is this:

- Does it work the same as `<Receiver>` in manifest file of android?

As from my test `<Receiver>` in manifest file it work whenever my app is opening or not, but the `Context.registerReceiver()` seem to work only when my app is opening.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Context.registerReceiver() (Dynamic method)registers for a broadcast only if the application is launched.

tag (Static method) in the manifest works irrespective of the fact the app is in foreground or background.

One case where  tag in manifest could fail is if the app is moved to sdcard..
Say you have registered for android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED,the boot event is triggered even before the mediascanner scans the sdcard. :P

Answer (score 0):

It will work as soon as this code is executed... :)

it's code !

Comment: Does it have any other way to make it work like this. Still use <Receiver> in manifest android but have other option to unregister it from receiveing sms.